# Can't use Segger J-link in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jtag

I installed Eclipse luna with ARM plug-in, installed Segger software, attached a J-link base to my board.  Running the command line Segger software it seems to connect just fine.
But in Eclipse, it's not seeing the J-link option and can't start the debugger. For some reason it's not showing up in the debug configuration options.
[image: Eclipse Debug Configuration screen shot]
[image: Eclipse Window Preferences]
[image: Installed plugins]

On a co-worker's machine it's working fine.  We're comparing setups but so far haven't found any discrepancies. We both have Windows 7.

If I try to debug it pops up a window saying it encountered a problem:
 Error with command: gdb --version
  Cannot run program "gdb": Launching failed

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it appears that somewhere in my attempts to get this going, I had clicked on the box for the GDB SEGGER J-Link debugger in Window | Preferences | Run/Debug | Launching | Launch Configurations.

I thought that was a box to include that debug option, but it is a filter to exclude that debugger, and that is apparently why it didn't show up in the debug configuration window.