# J Link does not appear in Eclipse Mars Menu(NOT A COPY)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, segger-jlink

This NOT a copy of [Can't use Segger J-link in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103317/cant-use-segger-j-link-in-eclipse)

He was able to solve his issue, and the solution does not work for me. I have installed Segger J-Link version 6.14, but the IDE is not displaying it under Windows->Preferences->Run/Debug as it supposedly should. PLEASE help.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has bothered answering and this MAY be useful to some other poor soul:

Try updating Eclipse GNU ARM tool chain from source forge.

In my case Source forge was acting up and I couldn't download the the utility properly. Hence the whole issue; if you do face this issue such as *"unable to read from repository"* or *"handshake failed"* it could be an issue with the JDK in your system: http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/blog/2017/01/29/plugins-install-issue/

The above link solved my issue with the Java environment and I was able to properly update Eclipse.

Once the tool chain was updated the Segger J-Link option appeared in the Run/Debug section and everything was right as rain.

Hope this helps.